# Open PDF file on client's browser directly from Java Servlet Class

Tags: java, servlets, plsql, pdf-generation

Hey Folks, So this is the rundown:

Essentially, what I want: PL/SQL Procedure call(using UTL_HTTP) --> Java Web Application, Servlet --> opens up a browser window and renders a PDF.

We use the package UTL_HTTP within our PL/SQL Procedure for this, as it has an option to send requests to external urls via the POST method. The only reason we use this package is to ensure our data is passed as POST parameters (apparently, there is no other way to open up external sites directly from PL/SQL procedures while passing parameters through the POST method). There are other means to provide urls directly and pass get parameters as part of the request url string, but this would expose sensitive parameters like username, password, serial id etc.

This http request from the PL/SQL procedure is intercepted by a servlet in our Java Web Application. Our Java Web Application is a Document Management Application and handles all the document management logic.

We managed to reach the servlet and also get a hold of the PDF and put it in the response.

Here's the catch: Since the originating application was a PL/SQL Procedure that sends the HTTP request directly to our Web Application, at no point is a browser window opened. So in our Java servlet class, we get hold of the PDF and write it onto the response. But we need to spawn a browser window to render the pdf. I found [this neat site](http://www.mkyong.com/java/open-browser-in-java-windows-or-linux/) that provides Java Code to open up a browser window directly from a java class. But the problem is that the browser window opens up at the server directly and not on the client.This browser window ought to open up in our client machine from where the http request was issued not at the server.

Any suggestions?

Cheers

Comment: So your concrete question is more: "How do I open a new browser window using PL/SQL procedure call?". It's apparently the one which the client has directly called.

Comment: It seems to me that you may have to start from other end. Open web browser and then send a request adn wait for response (pdf) from server. Can you describe more how you send the request?

Comment: I don't think you understand the request/response model of HTTP. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP

Comment: @BalusC: Actually "How do i open a new browser window using PL/SQL procedure call & the UTL_HTTP package".A plain joe opening of a url in a new browser is possible through other packages. like i said though UTL_HTTP is the only one that allows POST parameter passing.

Comment: @t-edd: I need to pass the request through a PL/SQL procedure. If i could pass th request from a browser, then i suppose it would be more straightforward. My problem is with getting it to work from a PL/SQL Procedure call and that too specifically with the UTL_HTTP package. Thanks

Comment: @Matt Ball: :) I suppose my question isn't the most efficiently worded but apart from the wikipedia entry, could you let me know specifically why you think i have misunderstood the model, a) it would help make my question clearer and b) help me understand the HTTP model better. Peace.

Comment: You really have to fire a HTTP request. Let the client invoke the servlet. Let the servlet invoke the stored procedure. Let the servlet return its result.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an PL/SQL Web aplication (using APEX or webToolkit) you can send to the browser the blob that you get from the UTL_HTTP call to the servlet